# Are there any ability to rename "Close" button of UILocalNotification?

Tags: cocoa-touch, background, uilocalnotification

Are there any ability to rename "Close" button of UILocalNotification? If it's not possible which API I should use instead UILocalNotification? I know about push service. But I would like to display notification locally without using some remote service.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Apple won't allow any application other than music player to run in background for more than 10 minutes.